# How to add Yii to Laravel Homestead's vagrant box?

Tags: php, laravel, yii, vagrant

i'm using Yii instead of Laravel for a project. I love Homestead, and Yii is running fine in it and hosted just fine, aside from using command lines like "yii migrate", which needs to be run from within vagrant ssh.

how do i add yii to my homestead box's config? i haven't dabbled much with vagrant other than homestead, but i feel like this should be pretty simple.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add another site to your homestead.yaml file. From the Laravel docs (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead):

Configure Your Nginx Sites

Not familiar with Nginx? No problem. The sites property allows you to easily map a "domain" to a folder on your Homestead environment. A sample site configuration is included in the Homestead.yaml file. Again, you may add as many sites to your Homestead environment as necessary. Homestead can serve as a convenient, virtualized environment for every Laravel project you are working on!

You can make any Homestead site use HHVM by setting the hhvm option to true:

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: myapp2.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp2/public
      hhvm: true
```

Comment: i already have it hosted and fine in the .yaml...it's running Yii commands in the command line that dont work.

Comment: Ah. Generally I just run yii commands from the /protected directory. You should be able to ssh in, go to that directory, and run the command.

Comment: i'm using WAMP instead for now. by any chance do you also deploy yii to laravel forge? if so, how do you do your migrations? if i add to my Deploy script on Forge, i get the same 'yii is not a command' problem.

edit: fixed it, thanks! had to do 'php yii migrate', not 'yii migrate'. cheers!

Comment: I think it should have been `yiic migrate` actually. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration